# Restore orgin repository using a remote repository

Tags: git, repository, restore

I'm trying to build some redundancy into our git deployment beyond the standard backup.  On paper, it seemed like it would be easy to restore a repository that multiple users have cloned using a repository that I created and linked / synced to using git remote.

In the past I have encountered problems with backup tapes either getting a bad backup or having to retrieve the tapes from off site. I'm looking at the remote possibility that the server that hosted the local branches for the lost repo suffered a catastrophic failure and I need to get a large source base back up and running in short order with minimal disruption.

The idea here would be to maintain an offsite server that simply idled along receiving updates from the production box.  When the production box imploded, I would then alias the server to a the backup server and make local copies of the "lost" remote branches

So far this is what I'm thinking for a restore path per repository:

```
- grep for the dead servers alias
- Parse for the remote branch names
- checkout the remote branches to the recovery repository
- Remove the dead servers alias
```

E.G. using tcsh:

foreach q (`git branch -a | grep kaboom-1 | cut -f 2 -d '/'`)

git checkout -b branch kaboom-1/branch

end

git remote rm kaboom

In testing this worked wonderfully but testing in a lab does not always directly translate into real world viability.  Has anyone performed this type of restore in the past or can you see a problem with this method?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit awkward because git has a nice backup feature with clone and the --mirror argument. I'd use git clone --mirror on the main repo and just keep updating my mirrors (which are completely identical) everytime something is pushed to the main repo. If something goes boom it's very easy to just clone a new repo from one of the mirror clones and carry on.

So just do:

```
git clone --mirror main_repo.git
```

as many times you want for cloned mirror of the main repo. Remember that --mirror implies --bare, so they dont have any working directories just like the main repo.

When something happens in the main repo and you want to sync your mirrors, in each mirror do:

```
git remote update
```

When this command finishes, this bare mirror clone is again identical to the main repo.

Comment: What do you do to restore the main repo back to the state of a mirror?